# How to change dimensions of rChart Iframe in html using RMarkdown?

Tags: html, r, iframe, r-markdown, rcharts

I am trying to incorporate rchart based on nvd3 library in my html documentation generated by RMarkdown. But I am unable to adjust the height of the resulting iframe in my html document.
As a result of that only half of my plot is visible. is there any solution for this problem using R?. I don't know any html or css. Here is my code chunk producing the plot.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,results='asis',comment=NA}
library(rCharts)
hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
n1$show("iframesrc",cdn=TRUE)
```
````

I even tried opening the html file in text editor and editing the `width` and `height` options of Iframe in vain.

Comment: Untested but I started on a solution that would style based on the parameters provided by rCharts in https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts/tree/iframe_config_size .  It works well on my end.  If you wanted to try you could devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rCharts@iframe_config_size")

Comment: here is the specific change https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts/commit/375fa36336c582427905427ad663caa4010b17ee

Comment: The `iframe` can be styled using CSS. Add `<style>iframe.rChart{height: 600px;width: 800px}</style>` if you want it to be bigger.

Comment: @timelyportfolio thankyou very much. I haven't tried that though.